# PHP - Problems on Change MySQL-enquiry from mysql_query to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Last year I have taken over the support of a webpage. This page in parts is still written with mysql_querys, which is the reason the server still runs on `PHP 5.6` (which causes unnecessary cost). To finally change the server to `PHP 7.x`, I'm actually working on change the scripts which still use `mysql_query` to PDO. In parts this worked without any problem. But now one of the scripts still won't work after a long search of mistakes. So I hope, that someone in this community can take a look at the script and help my finding the error.

The MysQL-query surely is correct and gives a result. So the problem must be at the PDO-syntax.

This was the Script how it is used till now (only the output is simplified by me):

```
$link = mysql_connect($sHost, $sUser, $sPass);
mysql_select_db($sDBName, $link);
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `" . $table . "` WHERE `index` = " . $_REQUEST['id'];
$erg1 = mysql_query($sql1, $link) or die("Fehler: " .mysql_error());
$result1[0] = mysql_fetch_array($erg1);
echo $result1[0]["kreis"];
```

Result:
Berlin

This is the script change to PDO now:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $id = $_GET['id'];
} else {
  die("Bitte eine ?id übergeben");
}

$pdo2 = new PDO(sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s', $sHost, $DBName), $sUser, $sPass);
$utf8 = $pdo2->prepare("SET NAMES UTF8");
$result_check = $utf8->execute();

$table = "orte_bb";
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `" . $table . "` WHERE `index` = ?";

$statementbb     = $pdo2->prepare($sql1);
$erg1              = $statementbb->execute(array($id));
while  ($result1        = $statementbb->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  echo $result1['kreis'];
}
```

Result:
empty array

This means, that the PDO `$statementbb` seams to file no data set. The question, I can't answer to me, ist, why this happens.

I would be happy, when some can take a look and give me a clue.

Thanks
bagira41berl

Comment: If `echo $result1[0]["kreis"];` worked in MySQL_, then `echo $result1['kreis'];` should be the same as the former.

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataset of orte_bb? Is there a column 'kreis'? Please also var_dump($result1);

Comment: if you are changing to pdo you can create a new pdo connection and add characterset in connection then use connection like so `$pdo2` and `execute();` without creating connection and character set each time. See here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo And https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Comment: @Markus Zeller:
Yes, the collum Kreis exist at the database, which is structured in the collums autor, ort, zeitraum. kreis, staat, anzeigenm, anzahl_ds, ansprechpartner, bild, link, typ, bemerkung and Primärschlüssel

Comment: The syntax looks all good for me and can't see an error. You could dump `$pdo2->errorInfo()` (after the execute) if there is a problem. Is the field `id` the primary key or is it really named `index`? `$erg1` should contain the number of matched rows. What's in there?

Comment: @Markus Zeller: $pdo2->errorInfo() says: Array ; and $erg1 seems to be empty (echo $erg1; has no effect)

Comment: Then it looks like the query returns no results. Try the query in a database manager like phpMyAdmin or DBeaver.

Comment: No, the error isn't in the SQL-Query. Even when I put in the old query ($sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `" . $table . "` WHERE `index` = " . $_REQUEST['id'];) which clearly workes with the old syntax the PDO-errorInfo statet "Array", It's seems like the browser (I use Google Chrome) isn't able to fill the result of the SQL-Query in the PDO-Array $erg1. And I don't know why, because there are no syntax errors in my opinion ...

Comment: btw. this are the var_dump-Results:  id => $string(2) "20" ; $ql1 => string(41) "SELECT * FROM 'orte_bb' WHERE `index` = ?" ; $statementbb =>  object(PDOStatement)#9019 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(41) "SELECT * FROM 'orte_bb' WHERE `index` = ?" } ; $erg1 => bool(false) ; $erg2 => array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }

Answer (score 0):

Now I found the error myself (which stuck in the detail). The error is in the first PDO-line:

```
$pdo2 = new PDO(sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s', $sHost, $DBName), $sUser, $sPass);
```

It's the variable, which is used for the database-name, where 1 letter is missed, which didn't stand out mutch. I korrected the syntax of this line to:

```
$pdo2 = new PDO(sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s', $sHost, $sDBName), $sUser, $sPass);
```

And now it works.

Best reagards
baerlinerbaer